# How can I access django admin's transliterator for slugs when using fixtures?

Tags: django, internationalization, slug

In the admin, if you enter in a slug two things are applied through JS:

1. The string is made slug-friendly
2. The string is transliterated if the language is not English, so for example Cyrillic Russian text gets converted into Transliterated Russian ( typed out in English )

I'm basically inserting a couple thousand rows and I need to access this. Does django provide a non-js server-side version of this transliterator which I can access to somehow do the insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I have to port over the `usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/django/contrib/admin/media/js/urlify.js` code unless I can figure out a way to programmatically load all articles on the client side and slugify themselves automatically.